# Interpretation of the correlation between a real function and a complex exponential.

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform, correlation

How does one interpret the correlation between a real function, x[n], and a complex exponential, $$e^{-j\omega n}$$, where j represents the imaginary part. Follows a well known example:

$$\chi\left(\omega\right)=\sum _{n=-\infty }^{\infty }\:x\left[n\right]e^{-j\omega n}$$

Comment: In your formula, do you consider $j$ or $\omega$ to be complex? If so, then there should be no ambiguity because they appear on both sides. If not, then the question is not clear. Usually an issue may arise, when one side is real and the other is complex. Once you get a hold of $e^{\pi i}+1=0$ things should go easier. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question to hopefully make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found the intuition I was looking for. In this case, the correlation is a complex number, and it is higher the farther away from the origin it is.
The multiplication of these two functions can be viewed as a "2D object" whose samples summation is a kind of a center of mass.

The correlation between these two functions is higher when the center of mass is farther away from the center.

Reference: https://youtu.be/spUNpyF58BY?t=1088